# How works the Apps versioning control of the App Store?

Tags: ios, version-control, app-store, version

I need to publish a new version (1.0.1.10) of an application that is published as version 1.0.1.

When trying to publish I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90060: "this bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '1.0.1.10' in the info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."
```

Can I only use three integers?

I did this procedure in the Google Play smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

> at most three non-negative integers

You can't use more, try something like 1.0.1100